# Asp.Net Core CS2001 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

Every time I attempt to build my Asp.Net Core project, I receive the following:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     C:\Code\Research and Development\Address Book\src\Address
>   Book\error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Code\Research and
>   Development\Address Book\src\Address Book\Book.deps.json' could not be
>   found.    Address Book    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets 241

The question, is how do I solve?  The depth isn't deep enough to cause.  All I can find is depth issues.  I'm assuming I'll have to tweak my MSBuild, but in what way I'm not sure.  Some insight into what causes the error and how to fix would be terrific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to currently be a bug with ASP.Net's Core Templating.

It is currently an open issue on GitHub titled

> VS2015: Asp.Net Core Template not working with Project name with spaces #580
>   https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/issues/580

and has been active as recently as 11 days ago.

As indicated by the title of the report, and based on the path you show, the problem is related to the fact that your project name has spaces. Perhaps in the mean time you can create a new project with no spaces as a workaround.